# Demoted, how to handle?

Tags: united-states, government, demotion, at-will

In Aug. 2019, I was demoted from Administrative Assistant to Secretary (I kept my pay), I wasn't a "good fit". I've never had a bad review in 15 years, not a blemish on my record, quite the opposite. I have emails and cards from my supervisors praising my work and work ethic. They did not hire for my position until January 2020 and gave this position a new title with many new duties. Several months later, the boss moves up and someone is promoted from within to the boss's spot. The new duties for the new office manager never materialize, she is doing the exact job I was, at approx $3.00 more an hour than I was making for the same job. Now the new office manager is overwhelmed and wants me to take over some of her duties. I have told the boss that I will not do any of her work, I was demoted, why would they want me to do the work?? If push comes to shove and I refuse, it's insubordination and should technically be fired. Am I valid by refusing to do the work that I used to do, or do I come off as bitter?

Comment: I am not in a union, but it is a local gov't job, and you're correct, I am bitter.  I just don't know how to get past it!

Comment: *Am I valid by refusing to do the work that I used to do, or do I come off as bitter?* Are you asking us what your employer will likely think or just asking us what we think? Either way your question doesn't seem to have a real goal and technically not on topic here. (FWIW, I think the question you've asked is a false dilemma.)

Comment: You do realize that this hierarchy of titles is really specific to your employer. In this case, it really doesn't matter what your title was, whether it's secretary or admin assistant. It's really the duties that you can truthfully list on your resume that are the most important.

Comment: Please specify your location.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk In the USA, if this is a civil service (public) position, then title is NOT specific to the employer, but governed by the civil service commission of that state, and whether that title is competitive, or non-competitive

Answer (score 12):

You need to check your contract, but basically, yes, in the United States if you're an at-will employee, they can fire you for that.

Do you really want to be looking for a new job during this pandemic? If I were you, I would swallow my pride. It's going to be easier for you to find a new job if you're still employed.

I'd suggest you bide your time. Help the other admin out for now. And start looking for another job in the meantime. Do what's in your best interest. Do not let your anger and ego make that decision for you.

> she is doing the exact job I was, at approx $3.00 more an hour

This part proves that you're underpaid and that you've probably stayed at this company for too long. The best way to get promoted is to switch employers often.

Answer (score 1):

Employment contracts are still contracts.  If you can show that the job duties being assigned to you are not in your current JD, but in the Administrative Assistant JD, the employer has to offer you consideration  (eg. Compensation) for taking on those additional job duties.  You can refuse and collect UI if you have the evidence that they were unfairly adding job duties to your position.

Comment: I am in the US, in an "At will" state. It is a gov't job, so it is a little harder to terminate me for any reason, but I would be giving them one by refusing to take over work for the office manager.

Comment: It's not incorrect.  Piling on additional job duties to a person can also be used as evidence of constructive dismissal. Most US employment is at-will.  They can fire an employee at any time, but unless they can show evidence of poor performance, they then have offer UI.  And being at-will does not prevent consideration.  If the employee is being given new job duties from another job position, the employer has terminated their present job contract.  The employer is free to do so, but they they have to offer UI.

Comment: @Christina: Legal consideration through unions is typically offered through a JEP committee.  Contact your shop steward and read your collective bargaining agreement on the details of your JEP process.

Comment: We do have numerous labor unions within our dept., the office workers are not covered.  Every job description we have for our department ends with, "other assorted duties" ,so they can get around this.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere:. It's constructive dismissal.  Christina was hired as an administrative assistant, was demoted with a pay decrease because she was told she was unqualified, but now she is being told she is qualified to perform the duties of the administrative assistant.  The employer breached her employment contract.  The employer would be able to get out of all UI claims by simply giving everyone duties they couldn't perform.   Constructive dismissal includes breaches of the employee contract.